# It's possible to hide body copy box for a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, wp-admin, plugin-types

I'm using [Wordpress Types](https://wordpress.org/plugins/types/) for create and manage Custom Post Types (CPT) at my blog and it works perfectly. I have created a CPT called *Espacio Publicitario* and I added also some custom fields (see image below). I need to hide **body copy box** since on this CPT is useless, can I do that? How? It will be hide just for this CPT not for the rest of the post, pages and so on

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a built in WordPress function for this, **remove_post_type_support** http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_post_type_support .

In your case you could use something like

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_init' );
function my_custom_init() {
    remove_post_type_support( 'custom_post_type_name', 'editor' );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can easily do it at the time of creating custom post type by using the `register_post_type( $post_type, $args )`
function. Don't use the 'editor' in supports parameter.

```
register_post_type('posttype name',$args);  
$args = array(  
        'labels' => $labels,  
        'public' => true,  
        'publicly_queryable' => true,  
        'show_ui' => true,   
        'show_in_menu' => true,   
        'query_var' => true,  
        'rewrite' => true,   
        'capability_type' => 'post',  
        'has_archive' => true,   
        'hierarchical' => false,  
        // on the supports param here you see no 'editor'  
        'supports' => array('title','author','thumbnail','excerpt','comments')    
    );
```